# Is it possible to manually send HTTP code 40x to client from ASP.NET Web service method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http, asmx

I would like to manually send an HTTP 40x error code to client from a **web method** in **c#** asp.net **web service**.

Specifically I need to send 400 (Bad request) or 401 (Unauthorized).

I was thinking about the flow to look like:

```
if (a <= 0)
{
   //send HTTP Error 400 - Bad request to client
   return;
}
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Doing this will violate the SOAP protocol

Comment: So i guess a better solution would be throwing a SoapException with ClientFaultCode?

Comment: yes. That's the correct way to do it. Even better would be to switch to WCF, which has better fault support (among many other things).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [response status code](http://scoperesolution.blogspot.com/2009/02/changing-response-status-code-in-aspnet.html)

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Statuscode = 404; //Your response here
Response.End;
```

I believe its important to clear the response first in case it is already partially populated

Comment: in .Net, you can use the HttpStatusCode enumeration to return the status code. Might make for easier readability if you're using esoteric status codes :) example:

HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

Comment: Ah didn't realise that enumeration existed - I bet the source code is hundreds of lines long in defining it!

Comment: Corrections to apply so that it works in C# : correct StatusCode casing and Response.End() is a method.